# Cant get a the data from my AJAX post request

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-core

I'm currently working on a ASP.net core 2.0 web app. And I want to parse a selected product id to the controller trough AJAX. In the controller I want to store it trough session or something. So far I can get a connection from AJAX to my Controller but my parameter is always null. The connection between my .js file and the Controller is not the problem. Here is my code:

My HTML

```
@Model  PCBuild.Models.PCBuildIndexModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "PC-Builder";
}
<asp:HiddenField ID="Selector" runat="server"/>
<div class="container-fluid" style="padding-top: 10px">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6" style="border-right: solid 1px #efefef">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <form asp-action="SendPcPart" method="post">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-9">
                            <h3>All parts:</h3>
                            <div class="list-group">
                                @foreach (var part in Model.PcParts)
                                {
                                    <a class="list-group-item pcselector" data-href="@part.EAN">@part._Name</a>
                                }
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-3">
                            <h5>Selected part: </h5>
                            <br />
                            <button class="btn-primary">Add</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <h3>Selected Items:</h3>
            <ul class="list-group"></ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is my .js file containing the AJAX:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.pcselector').click(function () {
    var pcPart = {
        EAN: $(this).data('href')
    };
    console.log(pcPart);

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '/PCBuild/SelectPcPart',
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        data: pcPart,
        beforeSend: function(xhr) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader("XSRF-TOKEN",
                $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val());
        },
        success: function(result) {
            console.log(result);
        },
        error: function(result) {
            console.log(result);
        }
    });
});
```

The .pcselector has a `data-heref = "1";` So the EAN has a value of 1.

My ASP.net Core 2.0 Controller:

```
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult SelectPcPart([FromForm] PcPart pcPart)
{
    return new JsonResult("Hello response back" + pcPart);
}
```

My PcPart class:

```
public class PcPart
{
    public int EAN { get; set; }
    public string _Name { get; set; }
    public string _Type { get; set; }
    public string Information { get; set; }
    public List<Propertie> Properties { get; set; }
}
```

I also replaced the `[FromForm]` with `[FromBody]` but that has no effect. I always get a empty PcPart class. I also removed it completely but that doesn't work either.

I also tried this version of my .js file:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.pcselector').click(function () {
    var pcPart = EAN: $(this).data('href');
    console.log(pcPart);

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '/PCBuild/SelectPcPart',
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        data: pcPart,
        beforeSend: function(xhr) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader("XSRF-TOKEN",
                $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val());
        },
        success: function(result) {
            console.log(result);
        },
        error: function(result) {
            console.log(result);
        }
    });
});
```

But that doesn't work either.

A screenshot of the empty class i get [Click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UV8Tx.png)

A screenshot of my console [Click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dIDN3.png)

**FIXED**
My javascript:

```
var pcPart = {
        "EAN": $(this).attr('data-href')
    };


data: JSON.stringify(pcPart),
```

My Controller:

```
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult SelectPcPart([FromBody] PcPart pcPart)
{
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Please show us your Html for .class pcselector. Are you getting any error in console?

Comment: Add the HTML and i don not get any errors in the console

Comment: Based on this Html, EAN should be `$(this).attr('data-href')` but there might be other problems with this code. Try not using [FromBody] nor [FromForm], create object with `var pcPart = {
        EAN: $(this).data('href')
    };`and then `JSON.stringify(pcPart)`

Comment: When I look in the console I get the value from my EAN (for example: 1). But when I look in the controller during debugging my parameter class is empty.

Comment: I have published a solution.

Answer (score 0):

The solution from @Camilo Terevinto is enough but if still not working then try using JSON.stringify(). Try this out

```
var dto = {
    pcPart: {
        EAN: $(this).data('href')
    }
};
console.log(dto);

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '/PCBuild/SelectPcPart',
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    data: JSON.stringify(dto),
    beforeSend: function(xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader("XSRF-TOKEN",
            $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val());
    },
    success: function(result) {
        console.log(result);
    },
    error: function(result) {
        console.log(result);
    }
});
```

Comment: I tried this but it does not work I still keep getting a PcPart that is null. I added a screenshot so you can see what I'm getting

Comment: You are not passing any thing except EAN and that also 0 from the data attribute so add pcPart: { EAN: $(this).data('href'), _Name: '', _Type: '', Information: '', Properties: []}

Comment: Well the problem is that when i look in the console my EAN = 1. But in the controller I get 0 (because the class is empty). So my Controller is not picking up any values. I also tried what you suggested in you last comment but that doesnt work either. I keep getting a empty class.